# How to rename Ubuntu One folders? Locked by syncdaemon?

Tags: ubuntu-one, ubuntu-one-windows, rename

tl;dr: **Does Ubuntu One detect renamed synced folders?**

I'm trying to rename a large synced folder ('Sync locally' checked) outside of Ubuntu One, but still inside the home folder on Windows.  Attempting to do so results in an error message:

```
Cannot rename foldernamehere: It is being used by another person or program.
Close any programs that might be using the file and try again.
```

Quitting ubuntuone-syncdaemon and renaming results in Ubuntu One not finding the synced folder (folder in ubuntuone-control-panel-qt becomes grayed out).  Ticking 'Sync locally' again causes Ubuntu One to begin downloading the synced folder with it's old name and ignoring the renamed folder.

Is there any way to locally rename a synced folder short of reuploading the entire folder under a new name?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hopefully in the future, Ubuntu One will make this work seamlessly with a built-in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to:

1) Stop syncing the folder to your computer

2) Rename it

Windows: quit ubuntuone-syncdaemon first by running the following command in Program Files\ubuntuone\dist: `u1sdtool -q`
Ubuntu: open system monitor, click the "Processes" tap, then perform killing the ubuntuone-syncdaemon.
On Ubuntu one app: un-tick the sync locally from the folder you want to rename.

3) From the ubuntu one site, remove the folder

4) Start syncing the new folder

Keep in mind that any other devices where this folder was synced will not rename it, and will stop syncing it as well.

The <strike>reupload</strike> renaming file check should be quick (15-20 min for 740MB), because the server already has a copy of your files.

Comment: Seems like the list of instructions would be nice to implement into the client as a single button.

I did a small test in Ubuntu and the instructions _almost_ work.  Except I had to restart the syncdaemon to start syncing the new folder.  Without restarting the syncdaemon, Ubuntu One detects a new folder to sync and is viewable online, but it doesn't sync (the folder is empty online and u1sdtool says IDLE).

I'll do another test with the large folder I had trouble with when I get back to the Windows computer.

Comment: I tried what you suggested on Windows.  It works, but only after a long time (20 minutes or so)!  Removing the folder from the Ubuntu One site does remove the folder from the server from the user's perspective (no trash folder), which makes things confusing since the server doesn't actually remove it.